# How do LCD monitors compare to LED monitors?

Tags: display, lcd, comparison, led

I'd love to get [this LCD monitor](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824005115), but I'm wondering if I should hold out until more LED monitors are on the market.

I really like the brightness of the [27" iMac monitor](http://www.apple.com/imac/design.html) and the above monitor is only rated at 5 cd/m2 less than that monitor, but wouldn't a back lit LED monitor appear to be much brighter than an LCD monitor?   How do LCD monitors compare to their LED counterparts?

Comment: Apple monitors are generally better quality.

Comment: In terms of general build quality or in terms of which specs (response time / brightness / contrast / color calibration)? In terms of specs I can't see much of a difference, though mac led monitors do seem brighter than some of the lcd monitors I've used. Either way I'll be forking out a lot of money so I'd like to make an informed decision.

Comment: I'd be more likely to upvote this question if it used the terminology better. Both monitor types we're discussing are LCD monitors. The difference is whether the LCD is edge-backlight with CCFL tubes shining on a reflector, versus being directly backlight by a matrix of LEDs.

So it's not "LCD monitor vs. LED monitor", it's "CCFL-backlit LCD vs. LED-backlit LCD"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever think you should wait for better display technology -- the answer is probably **yes**.
However, if you need a display today, your question should be which is the right one and will LED display prices fall faster than your urge for the display rises.

Some references,

1. PC-Mag: [How to Buy an LCD Monitor](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2362046,00.asp)
2. CNet: [LED vs. LCD: Which is better?](http://www.cnet.com.au/led-vs-lcd-which-is-better-339295938.htm)
3. [LED TV and LCD TV : A Comparative Study](http://gadgetophilia.com/led-tv-and-lcd-tv-a-comparative-study/)

You can also try [AskAboutGadgets](http://askaboutgadgets.com/faq) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Its mainly about brightness and power consumption. LED screens have less power consumption and generally higher brightness.

If you're looking at quality look up on [IPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal_display#In-plane_switching_.28IPS.29) (in-plane switching) screens.